# how to make a batch file to edit specific parameters in another text file

Tags: windows, batch, script, text-editors

i have a computer that streams on a close network, the stream is controlled by a text config file,
i would like to make a bat scripts that goes like:
enter your selected IP stream:
enter your port:
and so on...
and that after i enter the IP need it would either create a new file with all the parameters that i enter or edit the parameters of that file

- cannot install python on the computer

Comment: Yes it's possibe you can redirect whatever you want to a text fille by using echo Text>>Text.txt

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know what the file is going to look like, you can reconstruct the file.

Altering the file (eg, change its content) it much harder to do in batch and only slightly easier in powershell, but if you know what the file is going to be anyway, you can just output it and replace the original with a new copy.

There are two lines you need to know.

```
echo This is a test > file.txt
```

The above uses a single > char, which means, output the text `This is a test` to file.txt. If the file does not exist, create it, if it does exist, delete it and then create a new copy.

```
echo This is another test >> file.txt
```

The above uses two >> chars, which means, output the text `This is another test` to file.txt. If the file does not exist, create it, if the file does exist, append to it.

Each echo command will also add a new-line or carriage return at the end of the text, so every time you call the echo >> command, it is written to a new line.

You can use `set /p var=Question` to prompt for information (replace var for whatever you want) and then recall that by %var% later in the script.

Here's a small example script:

```
    @echo off

::  -- Ask for the person's name.
    set /p answer=What is your name?

::  -- write their name to a textfile.
    echo Your name is %answer% > info.txt

::  -- Ask for the person's age.
    set /p answer=How old are you?

::  -- write the age to the textfile also.
    echo You are %answer% years old. >> info.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@echo off

set /p Option1=Option1:
set /p Option2=Option2:
set /p Option3=Option3:

echo Option1=%Option1% >Options.txt
echo Option2=%Option2% >>Options.txt
echo Option3=%Option3% >>Options.txt
```

Comment: Please don't answer gimmee the codez questions. It only encourages other to ask poor questions.

Comment: @LPChip I'm reluctantly reopening this. However the OP shows no effort at all. That's why it was closed. This is a poor question and not the kind you should be answering.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for reopening. I understand where you're coming from. The reason why I think this question deserves an answer, is because sometimes you just lack the knowledge to even know where to start. By posting an answer that doesn't solve the problem but teaches instead, I think those are very valuable for SuperUser.

Comment: Well, i am sorry but if this sounds like a "gimmee codes" question, i dont have any experience in coding at all, and after around a hours of scouring the net for a lead, a friend suggested to ask that here.